# Choose rand and array assigned in to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working on flip in jquery, I choose random value from array and assigned that to flip option.

Here my html code

```
<div class="flipbox-container box100">
            <div id="flipbox1" class="flipbox">
                <h1>thesoftwareguy</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
<button id="btn-left">click</button>
```

Here my jquery

```
var directions = ['#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0'];
 var colors = ['top','right','bottom','left'];
 var ran_dir = directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
 var ran_col = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; 

$("#btn-left").on("click",function(e){
    $(".flipbox").flippy({
        color_target: ran_col,
        direction: ran_dir,
        duration: "750",
        verso: "<h1>Roses are Red.</h1>",
     });
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is when I click a button the flip is rotating continuously. How do I choose a random value and assigned to options of flip function.

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5T4aX/)

Comment: jsfiddle example: `GET http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/jquery.flippy.min.js 403 (Forbidden) -> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flippy'`

Comment: In firefox it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note, your color and direction lists are backwards.

```
var directions = ['#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0'];
var colors = ['top','right','bottom','left'];
```

should be

```
var colors = ['#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0'];
var directions = ['top','right','bottom','left'];
```

Also here is the fiddle I used (ended up just copying the jquery.flippy.min.js into the javascript section as linking didn't work.) The issue was what I mentioned above that caused it to infinitely loop, direction and color were backwards. I also added in the color and direction changing inside the click event rather than just the 1 time at load of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4TRE/2/

Comment: yeah, i think the weird issue came from the swapped directions vs colors.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine there in jsfiddle:

just create the variable on click, so that when ever you click, new values comes from the array.

```
var directions = ['#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0','#E0E0E0'];
var colors = ['top','right','bottom','left'];


$("#btn-left").on("click",function(e){
    var ran_dir = directions[Math.floor(Math.random() * directions.length)];
    var ran_col = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; 

    console.log(ran_dir, ran_col);

    $(".flipbox").flippy({
        color_target: ran_col,
        direction: ran_dir,
        duration: "750",
        verso: "<h1>Roses are Red.</h1>",
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

your jsfiddle is not working, because **jquery.flippy.js** is not being loaded. It's giving 403 loading issue.

You can see updated values here in console: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/5T4aX/3/

Comment: Yeah thanks, I am using this plugin http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/. I added that plugin in jsfiddle. But I dont know why its not loading in chrome.

Comment: may be some server restrictions... but that's fine. that will work locally for you. Just create the variable as I mentioned in the example above and this will work. Cheers!